# How to get last inserted id from mysql with entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

```
var forSentTable = new mailsent { Subject = Subject.Text, Mailbody = editor1.InnerText, SentTime = DateTime.Now, SentBy = mailFromEmail };

// var forSentTableBody = new MailSent { };
context.mailsents.Add(forSentTable);

//context.MailSents.Add(forSentTableBody);
context.SaveChanges();

//tried this one but not working with mysql(but it works with sql server)
var mailID = forSentTable.MailID;
```

Comment: how is this not working? what was expected? and what was the actual result?

Comment: in var mailID stored 0 rather than it should store the value of MailID from the above operation.

Comment: I just want last inserted row id in a variable.

Comment: what is the schema in your database (if you use database first)? is the MailID column defined as autoincrement with seed of 1?

Comment: yes mailID is the first column and it set to auto increment and it is incrementing

Answer (score 1):

if you use database first model . you  must set Identity  to value of StoreGeneratedPattern property of model .
 if you use code first model . try this

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public Guid ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm using Code first from database model.

Comment: you can use last piece of code . mean of this code is model id field will updated by framework